# Mark youtube embed video as seen in html site

Tags: html, youtube

I am a total beginner , and i have to make a tutorials site , and i thought that i use YouTube videos, using embed code , and i need to make somehow that the videos are marked as seen after a certain part of the video has been viewed, and i have no idea how.

```
<div class="s-12 m-6 l-4">
                  <iframe width="360" height="215" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D-5xpY4zH2c" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>      
                  <p class="subtitile">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                  </p>
               </div>
```

It doesn't matter how , i just need that the user know that the video has been seen or at least part of it.

Comment: This is a good question. looking through the youtube api, I don't see a way to get the watched percentage. I'm surprised there is not a "watched %" data.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Comment: I don't need to show it, i need that the user know that the video has been watched, or at least part of it

Comment: I found something, it triggers an event when the video ends, but i need it to trigger the event after a part of the video has been played, if the event can be displaying a text "seen" or something like that.         player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
    if(state === 0){
        // the video is end, do something here.
    }
});